# How to arrange video in the UITextView after text in UITextView?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uitextview

I want to place my video after a text in the `UITextView`, I searched how to do that but I didn't
find anything that can help me.

Or if it possible video out of the `UITextView`, but the video will shows only when I'll scroll all text.

Thank's for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the little information you provided here is one solution:

1. Use a `UIScrollView` and put the views inside it
2. Here you have two options:

   2a. If you use `UITextView` specific features like editing, selecting, detecting of data (phone, url, ..) use `UITextView` but its height fit to the height of the text in it.

   2b. If you don't use `UITextView` specific features, just use a `UILabel` instead.
3. Put the video view in the `UIScrollView` too